# awk sum multiple columns

Tags: awk

How can I calculate the SUM for all the individual columns (115 Columns)?

Input.txt

```
1st,2nd,3rd,4th,5th,Till-115thColumn
51,34,27,67,88,99
56,39,32,72,93,104
66,49,42,82,103,114
```

Output.txt

```
1st,2nd,3rd,4th,5th,Till-115thColumn
173,122,101,221,284,317
```

I tried this command:

```
awk -F"," 'BEGIN {sum=0; OFS=","} {for (i=1 i<=NF; i++) a[i]+=$i } END {for (i in a) print a[i]}' Input.txt
```

but I am not getting the required output.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This can be a way:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
     NR==1{print}
     NR>1{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[i]+=$i}
     END{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf a[i] OFS; printf "\n"}' file
```

It sets the comma as input/output field separator and then stores the sum of each column in an array `a[]`. Finally, it loops through the results and prints them. Note `NR==1` is user to print the header.

For your given input it returns:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NR==1{print} NR>1{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[i]+=$i} END{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf a[i] OFS; printf "\n"}' file
1st,2nd,3rd,4th,5th,Till-115thColumn
173,122,101,221,284,317,
```

#### Why wasn't your script working?

Because you missed a `;` in the `for` declaration:

```
awk -F"," 'BEGIN {sum=0; OFS=","} {for (i=1 i<=NF; i++) a[i]+=$i } END {for (i in a) print a[i]}' a
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near )
```

so this makes it:

```
$ awk -F"," 'BEGIN {sum=0; OFS=","} {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) a[i]+=$i } END {for (i in a) print a[i]}' file
                                             ^
174
124
104
225
289
317
```

Answer (score 3):

your codes did the calculation correctly, but has problem in output part:

```
awk -F, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)a[i]+=$i}
        END{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)printf "%d%s", a[i], (i==NF?"\n":",")}'file
```

Comment: I really like the trick not to have a trailing comma and have a new line at the end. Good one!

Comment: +1 for seeing the `ternary` beauty with coffee in the morning.

Comment: while using cygwin, last 2 columns "SUM-Output" is not coming , any idea ?/cygdrive/g
$ cat Input.txt
a1st,b2nd,c3rd,d4th,e5th,Till-115th
51,34,27,67,88,99
56,39,32,72,93,104
66,49,42,82,103,114

/cygdrive/g
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NR==1{print} NR>1{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[i]+=$i} END{for (i=1;i<=NR;i++) printf a[i] OFS; printf "\n"}' Input.txt
a1st,b2nd,c3rd,d4th,e5th,Till-115th
173,122,101,221,