# awk to parse csv file

Tags: parsing, csv, awk

My input file is:

```
1601260800434:0:0:0:0:0:157:154:1022:1020:764:765:0:0:0:0:0:0:3:0:0:0:796:223:0:596:168:13247:12178:0
1601260800434:0:0:0:0:0:144:143:1100:1103:914:912:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:822:280:0:715:196:13469:12248:0
1601260815434:0:0:0:0:0:184:178:1005:1006:830:829:0:0:0:0:0:0:2:0:0:0:781:225:0:629:200:13227:12170:0
1601260815434:0:0:0:0:0:182:181:1304:1307:912:914:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:0:0:0:988:317:0:720:193:13537:12330:0
1601260830434:0:0:0:0:0:162:157:1064:1065:873:873:0:0:0:0:0:0:5:0:0:0:846:219:0:705:168:13217:12176:0
1601260830434:0:0:0:0:0:173:168:1273:1273:1004:1002:0:0:0:0:0:0:5:0:0:0:939:332:0:771:229:13531:12328:0
```

How can I have sum per column for all columns when first field is the same?
One total for 1601260800434, another one for 1601260815434, etc. So I would expect this output:

```
1601260800434:0:0:0:0:0:301:297:2122:2123:1678:1677:0:0:0:0:0:0:3:0:0:0:1618:503:0:1311:364:26716:24426:0
1601260815434:0:0:0:0:0:366:359:2309:2313:1742:1743:0:0:0:0:0:0:3:0:0:0:1769:542:0:1349:393:26764:24500:0
1601260830434:0:0:0:0:0:335:325:2337:2338:1877:1875:0:0:0:0:0:0:10:0:0:0:1785:551:0:1476:397:26748:24504:0
```

Any idea what awk code should be? The code should take into account any number of fields/columns. Many thanks!

Edit: the other solution marked as possible duplicate will not check when first field changes.

Comment: you'll need to explain better the rule for your second step. As all records begin with 1601260815434, shouldn't there be only 1 totals rec for that number? Please fix your Q above, rather than reply in comments. Good luck.

Comment: do you want to sum  each column after the first one?  is the number of columns always the same?

Comment: Hi Shellter, the rows start with 5 unique values in this example (1601260800434 or 1601260815434 or 1601260830434 etc). Claudio, the number of columns can vary from 3 to around 61. I need to find a code that covers all these cases (as I have for step 1). Thank you!

Comment: Come on, do we REALLY need to see about 30 lines of 50-character wide strings for you to demonstrate your problem? Come up with a briefer example that has less than 10 lines, each of less than 10 characters. Put some effort into making your example as concise as possible if you want other people to be willing to put the effort into trying to understand your example so they can help you.

Comment: Question was updated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [awk sum multiple columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22042400/awk-sum-multiple-columns)

Comment: This question is tagged [tag:awk], but I don't see any awk code in the question. I'm submitting a close vote, because this question is missing a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Happy to help you improve your programming, but the process has to start with *your* attempt to solve your problem. Happy to retract the close vote if you update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F: '{keys[$1]; for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) sums[$1,i]+=$i}
        END{for(k in keys)
               {printf "%s",k;
                for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s", FS sums[k,i];
                print ""
               }
           }' file
1601260830434:0:0:0:0:0:335:325:2337:2338:1877:1875:0:0:0:0:0:0:10:0:0:0:1785:551:0:1476:397:26748:24504:0
1601260800434:0:0:0:0:0:301:297:2122:2123:1678:1677:0:0:0:0:0:0:3:0:0:0:1618:503:0:1311:364:26716:24426:0
1601260815434:0:0:0:0:0:366:359:2309:2313:1742:1743:0:0:0:0:0:0:3:0:0:0:1769:542:0:1349:393:26764:24500:0
```

Comment: Perfect, it works, thank you! Where do I send the beer?